# HTTP Request String to object

Tags: rust

I am trying to convert a incoming HTTP request like this:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:8080
User-Agent: curl/8.1.2
Accept: */*
```

Into a HTTP object. This is my current code:

```
impl Http {
    fn from_str(str: &str) -> Self {
        println!("{}", str);
        let lines : std::vec::Vec<&str> = str.lines().collect();
        let request_line : std::vec::Vec<&str> = lines[0].split_whitespace().collect();
        
        let method = request_line[0];
        let path = request_line[1];
        let host = lines[1].split_whitespace().collect::<std::vec::Vec<&str>>()[1];
        
        Http {
            method: method.into(),
            path: path.into(),
            host: host.into(),
            cookies: std::collections::HashMap::new(),
        }
    }
}
```

It does work. But my current implementation is to split the string into whitespace and assume the first line is always contains the method and the path; the second line contains the host,...

But what if a request comes in which does not follow that order? What is a more trustworthy way to achieve this?

Comment: https://crates.io/crates/httparse